# How to display individual bar values using ggplot() + geom_bar() without specifying y values

Tags: r

I have a sample of my original data frame called df and I'm trying to display the exact number of each bar on the bars.

I tried using the function geom_text(), but for using geom_text() I would need to define a y.
But using geom_bar() doesn't require defining a y.

This is a sample of my dataframe:

```r
df
    taet distance_km
   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     4           4
 2     1           6
 3     2           5
 4     4           7
 5     4           3
 6     3           5
 7     1           5
 8     1           4
 9     2           4
10     1           2
11     1           1
12     4           6
13     1           4
14     1           7
15     1           2
16     4           7
17     1           4
18     4           4
19     1           6
20     2           9
21     1           5
22     4           4
23     1           1
24     1           6
25     1           3
26     1           3
27     5           2
28     1           2
29     1           8
30     1           3
```

This is my code for ggplot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(distance_km)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ taet) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = 1:9)
```

The shown data frame is only a little share of my original data frame.
It is a lot harder to read/guess the exact number of each bar out of the diagram.
I would like to display the exact number of each bar on the top of each bar, so the reader can easily identify the exact value of each bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include some extra arguments in `geom_text`.  Below I have used `geom_label`, which adds a white background and I think might be clearer than `geom_text` in this case.  You might want to add a `size` argument too, or you could use `nudge_y` to raise it above the top of the bar.  See the help for `geom_text` for details of the various options.

```
ggplot(df, aes(distance_km)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ taet) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_label(stat="count", aes(label=stat(count))) +  #or use geom_text here
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = 1:9)
```

[image]

Comment: @C.Toni The best way to split the bars according to a `SEX` variable would be to replace the `geom_bar` term with `geom_histogram(aes(fill=factor(SEX)), position = "stack", binwidth = 1)`

Comment: Thank you!
`geom_histogram` didn't work in my code. I complemented my code with `ggplot(..., fill=factor(SEX))` and `geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(SEX)))`.
But now I do have another question.
Is there a way to display the numbers for each SEX on each bar?

Comment: I have tried many solutions and finally found a simple answer to my question in the comment above.
But thank you very much for your help!